# Reloading and then refreshing in same function jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-visualization, reload

In my PHP application I'm using 2 php files.

1. **chart.php** - Page contains a google chart.

   ```
   <div id="chart_div" style="height:100%;width:100%">
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

     function drawStuff() {
       var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Opening Move', 'Percentage'],
         ["King's pawn (e4)", 44],
         ["Queen's pawn (d4)", 31],
         ["Knight to King 3 (Nf3)", 12],
         ["Queen's bishop pawn (c4)", 10],
         ['Other', 3]
       ]);

       var options = {
         title: 'Chess opening moves',
         width: 900,
         legend: { position: 'none' },
         chart: { title: 'Chess opening moves',
                  subtitle: 'popularity by percentage' },
         bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
         axes: {
           x: {
             0: { side: 'top', label: 'Percentage'} // Top x-axis.
           }
         },
         bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
       };

       var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
       chart.draw(data, options);
           google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
     };

     function selectHandler() {
        window.location.href = "chart.php";
     }
   </script>
   ```

**2. index.php** - Home page where I'm including *chart.php* in a div

```
<div style="width:40%">
require_once 'chart.php';
</div>
```

On clicking the chart in *index.php* page , it will call `selectHandler()` and  redirect to chart.php.

The issue is, the chart in chart.php (after redirecting from index.php) is showing in small size similar to the chart display in index.php. Once I refreshes the chart.php it will display the chart in correct size.

Is there any function in jquery to refresh a page by reloading other than using `location.reload()`.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is chart.php set up to be both a partial view and a full page endpoint?

Comment: @charlietfl. In chart.php, it will be shown in full page width. In index.php its showing upto 40% width only. The issue is its retaining the width of chart once I redirect to chart.php page.

Comment: But how do you differentiate between it having a full html document vs only partial html? Just opening what you are showing is not a valid html page and you can't embed a full page as a partial

Comment: Hmmm.... what does `<div style="width:40%">` do? Hmmm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try redrawing the chart,
use an inline function on your select handler,
so you can still access your chart, data, and options.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
  window.location.href = "chart.php";
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```